# postman POST request doesn't work in nodejs (accessing 3rd party API)

Tags: node.js, post, web-scraping, http-post, postman

I've been playing around with some web scraping but I've run into an issue I can't figure out; Using a nodejs server (on my local computer) I cannot get passed a permission error barring me from accessing the data. What is confusing to me most is that using the chrome extension "Postman" I don't run into the permission errors, but using the code generated by postman, I do (as well as fiddling with variations of my own scratch code).

Do I have to be using a live server? Do I need to include some extra items in the headers that aren't being put there by Postman? Is there some layer of security around the API that for some reason Postman has access do that a local machine doesnt?

Any light that can be shed would be of use. Note that there is no public documentation of the SmithsFoodAndDrug API (that I can find), so there aren't necessarily APIKeys that are going to be used. But the fact that Postman can access the information makes me think I should be able to on a node server without any special authentication set up.

In Summary:

1. I'm looking at SmithsFoodAndDrug product information, and found the API where they are grabbing information from.
2. I figured out the headers needed in order to get local price information on products (on top of the json body format for the POST request)
3. Using postman I can generate the POST request and retrieve the desired API results
4. Using nodejs (and the code generated by postman to replicate the request) with both 'request' module and standard 'http' module request module I receive permission errors from the server.

Details: (assume gathering data on honeycrisp apples (0000000003283) with division-id of 706 and store-id of 00144)

1. http://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/products/api/products/details
2. Headers are 'division-id' and 'store-id'. Body is in format of {"upcs":["XXX"],"filterBadProducts":false} where XXX is the specific product code.
3. Here are the [Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4vAN.png) in postman. Here are the [Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCwjt.png) settings in postman. The following is a portion of the json response (which is what I want).

   ```
   {"products": [
       {
           "brandName": null,
           "clickListItem": true,
           "countryOfOrigin": "Check store for country of origin details",
           "customerFacingSize": "price $2.49/lb",
           ...
           "calculatedPromoPrice": "2.49",
           "calculatedRegularPrice": "2.99",
           "calculatedReferencePrice": null,
           "displayTemplate": "YellowTag",
           "division": "706",
           "minimumAdvertisedPrice": null,
           "orderBy": "Unit",
           "regularNFor": "1",
           "referenceNFor": "1",
           "referencePrice": null,
           "store": "00144",
           "endDate": "2018-09-19T00:00:00",
           "priceNormal": "2.55",
           "priceSale": "2.12",
           "promoDescription": "About $2.12 for each",
           "promoType": null,
           ...
           "upc": "0000000003283",
           ...
       }
   ],
   "coupons": {},
   "departments": [],
   "priceHasError": false,
   "totalCount": 1 }
   ```
4. When using the code given by postman to replicate the request, I get the error saying 'You don't have permission to access "http://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/products/api/products/details" on this server.
   Reference #18.1f3de93f.1536955806.1989a2b1.' .

   ```
   // Code given by postman
   var request = require("request");

   var options = { method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/products/api/products/details',
     headers: 
      { 'postman-token': 'ad9638c1-1ea5-1afc-925e-fe753b342f91',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'store-id': '00144',
        'division-id': '706',
        'content-type': 'application/json' },
     body: { upcs: [ '0000000003283' ], filterBadProducts: false },
     json: true };

   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
     if (error) throw new Error(error);

     console.log(body);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

change `headers`

```
    headers: 
       { 
         'store-id': '00144',
         'division-id': '706'
//'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
```